# Get the latest date in SQL from text format

Tags: sql, date, csv, sqldatetime

I'm trying to get the latest date from a csv file , the dates are stored in this form

```
NOV 14 2010
FEB 1 2012
JUN 18 2014
```

and my query is like

```
SELECT Max(date) from table
```

I'm getting

```
NOV 14 2010
```

any idea ?

Comment: What database do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are likely being considered strings(varchar) not DateTimes. Try:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(TABLE.date as DateTime)) FROM TABLE
```